# Reverse proxy with haproxy not forwarding host

Tags: reverse-proxy, haproxy, appfog

I am trying to configure HAproxy running on one server to forward requests to some apps I have running on appfog but it has stopped working. I have checked my configurations but I can't spot the problem.

I suspect the host information is not being forwarded correctly because when I enter the domain1.com I am routed to domain1.app.com on appfog but the server throws a 404.

This is my configuration file -

```
global
        maxconn   4096
        user      haproxy
        group     haproxy
        daemon
        log       127.0.0.1 local0  info
        log       127.0.0.1 local1  notice

defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull
        option  originalto
        option  forwardfor
    stats   enable
    stats   auth domain1:xxxxxx
        option  httpclose
        retries 3
        option  redispatch
        maxconn        2000
        contimeout      5000
        clitimeout      50000
        srvtimeout      50000

backend domain1_at_appfog
        reqirep ^Host:\ domain2.com Host:\ domain2.web.app.com
        server appfog1 domain2.web.app.com:80

backend domain2_at_appfog
        reqirep ^Host:\ domain1.com Host:\ domain1.app.com
        server appfog2 domain1.app.com:80 

backend local_host_site
        server this1 127.0.0.1:8080

frontend superliciousLove *:80
        acl www_domain1 hdr_dom(host)  -i www.domain1.com
    acl local_host url_sub www2
    use_backend domain1_at_appfog if www_domain1
        use_backend local_host_site if local_host
        default_backend   domain1_at_appfog
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the example provided, if it is accurate, then the problem is here:

```
backend domain1_at_appfog
    reqirep ^Host:\ domain2.com Host:\ domain2.web.app.com
    server appfog1 domain2.web.app.com:80
```

Your ACL is checking for www.domain1.com, and routes to `backend domain1_at_appfog`. However, you are doing a replacement on `domain2.com` instead of `domain1.com`, and appfog is only seeing `domain1.com` instead of the re-mapped host name.

If you need the backend to support more than one domain, you can change your use of `reqirep` to replace all matching hosts with the appfog host:

```
backend domain1_at_appfog
    reqirep ^Host: Host:\ domain1.web.app.com
    server appfog1 domain1.web.app.com:80

backend domain2_at_appfog
    reqirep ^Host: Host:\ domain2.app.com
    server appfog2 domain2.app.com:80
```